# Which satellite is this very bright object?

Tags: artificial-satellite

For the past few years, I've been spotting this "star" periodically in the night sky. Except it's not a star because it doesn't twinkle. And I don't think it's Venus, because I've observed it high in the sky at all hours of the night. So, it must be a satellite !

From what I can see, it appears to be the brightest object in the night sky, except for the moon. I took a look at the horizon map on in-the-sky.org. The only bright object listed (which was roughly in the correct orientation on the map to the actual spot) was SR-16 R/B, a spent rocket stage from 1993. Something tells me that probably isn't it. So, I turn to the experts...

I took this photo at 6:07am on Tuesday, October 10th 2023, EST at GPS coordinates (40.7192,-73.8614), facing roughly due east. The uppermost object towards the right (east-southeast) is the crescent moon (crappy phone camera, sorry), with the bright spot below it being object in question.

What is this object?

[image]
Source: Original poster

Comment: "I've observed it high in the sky at all hours of the night. So, it must be a satellite !" Most naked-eye-bright satellites cross the sky quickly, in a matter of moments. If it's visible for a long time it's probably not a satellite.

Comment: The ISS is the largest and brightest artificial satellite in orbit, and it generally crosses the sky in 5 minutes or less. If you're seeing it for more than 10 minutes it's not a satellite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

6:07am on Tuesday, October 10th 2023, EST at GPS coordinates (40.7192,-73.8614)

looks like venus to me:

[image]

fed the same in in-the-sky:

[image]

Comment: ...I feel stupid. I do have a general knowledge of orbital mechanics and whatnot, but I'm an amateur amateur astronomer, heh.

Answer (score 6):

While the object you displayed is definitely Venus, that you wrote

> And I don't think it's Venus, because I've observed it high in the sky at all hours of the night.

If you've seen a bright, non-twinkling object "at all hours of the night", what you've seen in the middle of the night is not Venus. If you see a bright, non-twinkling object at night more than 47° above the horizon, it's not Venus. As the morning star, Venus rises at most three hours before sunrise. As the evening star, it sets at most three hours after sunset. Venus is not visible at all hours of the night.

I suspect the bright, non-twinkling object you have seen more than three hours after sunset (or earlier than three hours before sunrise) was either Jupiter or Saturn. Neither is as bright as Venus at its brightest, but Jupiter sometimes comes somewhat close.

It's easy to confuse Jupiter and Venus as both are silvery white and both are rather bright compared to the twinkling stars. Right now, one can see both Venus and Jupiter in the pre-dawn sky. When Venus is rising, Jupiter is above 47° in elevation, and a bit to the west of vertical.